# How to checkout only Jenkinsfile instead of the whole branch while using Bitbucket Pullrequest Builder Plugin?

Tags: git, jenkins, bitbucket, jenkins-pipeline

**Background:**

The Jenkins plugins I'm working with are:

- Bitbucket Plugin
- Bitbucket Pullrequest Builder Plugin

The company I work for is using Jira + Bitbucket.

I've implemented automatic builds in Jenkins by creating a Jenkins "Bitbucket team" job which automatically scans the whole company's Bitbucket organization repositories and all branches within each repository and automatically builds jobs for each branch within each repository.

Once a pull request is opened or a commit is pushed to one of these repositories, Jenkins triggers a build for that branch and that pull request respectively.

The `Jenkinsfile` of the pipeline is identical on all repositories.

The job has some stages which require running Docker and for that there's a Jenkins slave installed with Docker.

One of the stages is running `docker-compose` and for that it requires a `docker-compose.yml` file which resides in the repository.

**Now my problem:**

The job which is responsible for the scanning of the BitBucket organization resides on the Jenkins master which means that the first checkout is done in the Jenkins master workspace while one of the main stages of the build (the `docker-compose`) takes place on the Jenkins slave "Docker" machine so when it gets to that stage the files from the repository are missing there, so I use `checkout scm` again within the `node('docker'){}` to pull the newly committed files into the docker machine workspace.

That means that the repository is cloned twice; once by the scanning job which identifies the commit/PR - into the Jenkins master's workspace and a second time by the Jenkins docker slave into it's workspace.

For now the company's repositories are not that large but they could become large in the future and I want to make sure that the jobs are finishing their run as soon as possible.

So I was wondering if it's possible to somehow override "BitBucket plugin" to check out only Jenkinsfile from the branch where the commit/PR has been done instead of the whole branch.

Is such a thing possible?

Comment: We left bitbucket because the tooling for it in Jenkins is not very good. I wrote a bunch of shell scripts for the migration to Github. Maybe they'll help you :)
https://github.com/Liath/bitbucket-github

Answer (score 2):

In the [pipeline options](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#available-options) you can set `skipDefaultCheckout`.

> Skip checking out code from source control by default in the `agent` directive. For example: `options { skipDefaultCheckout() }`

Then it will discover (and run) your Jenkinsfile, but not automatically checkout the whole branch.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check out a single file you can do that in a shell with this command:

```
git archive --remote=git@git.xxx.xxx:project/your-repo.git HEAD:folder file | tar -x
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm trying to override/workaround the behavior of the Bitbucket plugin which does a full checkout by default upon Bitbucket team scan, do you know if it can be done?